# Internet Explorer makes HEAD and GET requests for same <object>svg

Tags: svg, http-headers, httprequest, internet-explorer-11

I have an external svg file in my MVC project like this:

```
<object id="demo" type="image/svg+xml" data="/Content/images/demo.svg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display:block; right:0; position:absolute "></object>
```

There is only GET request in FF, ME and Chrome but if I open my project in IE 11, it makes HEAD and GET requests same time. I couldn't find how to avoid. Is it normal? or am I in trouble? Saying trouble, because that svg file size is approximately 4.5 Mb. Network monitor looks like :

```
File     Protocol  Method    Type         Transferred   Cause 
---------------------------------------------------------------
demo.svg  HTTP/2    HEAD  image/svg+xml     4.55 MB       -
demo.svg  HTTP/2    GET   image/svg+xml     4.55 MB    document
```

**UPDATE-Workaround:**

Well, i found an odd way. In fact a bit lagging while trying to get DOM elements but still better than make people download extra 4.5Mb every visit, right ?

I removed object element, loaded svg file via `XMLHttpRequest`  object and set the content of a div with `responseText`(returns whole svg file as text) property. Inevitably a loading image added just before call function to say: "hey it's gonna be lag for a sec don't worry."

By the way, i tried to use `Blob` object to create url for `<object>` element's data attribute but it doesn't work in IE with `<object>`.

I still want to know how to prevent HEAD request in IE.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `<object>`. Try using `<img>` instead:

```
<img src="/Content/images/demo.svg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display:block; right:0; position:absolute ">
```

Comment: i need DOM elements in svg document and also not suitable for inline usage because of its size, so i have to use it as <object> element :/  thanks for reply